# Python Django Admin Clean() Method not overiding values

Tags: python, django, admin

Maybe I am missing something here, but according to the django docs, I should be able to overide values sent from an admin form from within the clean() method.
From django docs

```
def clean(self):
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
    # Don't allow draft entries to have a pub_date.
    if self.status == 'draft' and self.pub_date is not None:
        raise ValidationError('Draft entries may not have a publication date.')
    # Set the pub_date for published items if it hasn't been set already.
    if self.status == 'published' and self.pub_date is None:
        self.pub_date = datetime.date.today()
```

I have stripped down my code and am just trying a basic example here from within the admin

Models.py

```
class Test(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=255,)

def clean(self):
    self.name = 'Robin Hood'
    return self
```

So when I try and add a new Test record, if I leave the name field empty, it should grab the value from the clean method and save.

What happens though, is that the form doesnt validate, and the field remains empty.

Am I missing something blantantly obvious here?

Answer (score 8):

You won't even get as far as running the model clean method. Django will run the form's validation code first, and because your field is not defined with `blank=True`, the form will enforce that constraint first.

What you should do is to override the form, setting `required=False` to the `name` field, then writing a *form* clean method which sets values in - and returns - `self.cleaned_data`:

```
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Test

    def clean(self):
        self.cleaned_data['name'] = 'Robin Hood'
        return self.cleaned_data
```

and reference that form in your admin class:

```
class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = TestForm
```

Answer (score 5):

`clean()` method of model is not called when objects are created from Admin Site. `clean()` is called only after `full_clean()` but Saving and object on Django Admin Site does not call that function.

As you can see in the [official documentation for Mode.clean()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean), `full_clean()` is called to catch extra validation errors.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError, NON_FIELD_ERRORS
try:
    article.full_clean()
except ValidationError, e:
    non_field_errors = e.message_dict[NON_FIELD_ERRORS]
```

You will need to override save() method for this.

Comment: Your link to the "official" documentation gives 404.

Comment: Maybe admin validation is possible: [Adding custom validation to the admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin)

Answer (score 4):

2 small steps to resolve this issue :)

1)full_clean() is called before clean(), so set pub_date in models.py as:

```
pub_date = models.DateField(null=True)
```

2)just return cleaned_data dict from clean function to manipulate pub_date model field value.Try this:

```
def clean(self):
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
    # Don't allow draft entries to have a pub_date.
    if self.cleaned_data['status'] == 'draft' and self.cleaned_data['pub_date'] is not None:
        raise ValidationError('Draft entries may not have a publication date.')
    # Set the pub_date for published items if it hasn't been set already.
    if self.cleaned_data['status'] == 'published' and self.cleaned_data['pub_date'] is None:
       self.cleaned_data['pub_date'] = datetime.date.today()
    return self.cleaned_data
```

- have mercy on other developers and import ValidationError on top of forms.py file rather then importing it in every clean function now and then :)

Answer (score 1):

try this. You need to return all the cleaned data. Also, you will need to set `blank=True` on your form field to allow it to be blank if you already haven't done so.

```
def clean(self,*args,**kwargs):
    cleaned_data = super(Test,self).clean(*args,**kwargs)

    # Check to see if name is entered, if not set it to robin hood. 
    if not cleaned_data['name']:
        cleaned_data['name'] = 'Robin Hood'

    return cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a model with three fields, field1, 2 and 3, and you want set field3 as a combanation of field1 and field2, you can write just like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = ...
    field2 = ...
    field3 = ...

    def clean(self):
        #simply set field3 as the value you want, and note that RETURN is NOT NEEDED in this function
        self.field3 = "%s-%s" % (self.field1, self.field2)
```